# Having a hard time getting elements to line up correctly

Tags: html, css

I thought I was doing everything correctly but am having a hard time getting the elements in my html to center and position correctly, everything looks off but I don't know if it's my nav bar or if the actual div blocks are off.

Tried margin: 0 auto; tried text aligning everything to center. I used position relative to put a poor band-aid on the problem but I know it's not the best way to do it.

```
.flex{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.testimonial{
position: relative;
top: 250px;
left: 10px;
float: left;
width: 33%;
height: 500px;
padding: 10px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}

.testimonial img{
position: relative;
left: 50%;
top: 65px;}

.testimonial p{
position: relative;
text-align: center;
top: 150px;
}

.testimonial a{
position: relative;
text-align: center;
top: 150px;
}

<div class="testimonial">
    <img class="tractors" alt="tractor" src="images/tractor.jpg">
    <h1>ABOUT US</h1>
    <p>Come to Hi-Bar Tractor Services to get all of your tractor 
servicing needs. Our dedication to excellence and customer satisfaction 
makes us the go to resource for all of San Diego.
</div>

<div class="testimonial">
  <img class="tractors" alt="tractor3" src="images/landscape.jpg">
  <h1>SERVICES</h1>
  <p>Field/Pasture disc service, manure, junk, debris hauling, demolition 
and more! Visit our services page for more awesome things that we can do 
for you!</p>
  <a href="services.html">Learn More!</a>
</div>

<div class="testimonial">
    <img class="tractors" alt="tractor2" src="images/tractor2.jpg">
    <h1>INDUSTRY LEADER</h1>
    <p>Sean has been working with tractor repair and landscaping his whole 
life making him a wealth of knowledge about any problems that you might 
encounter. <a href="#contact">Call him now!</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: add u r html code also

Comment: Start from the beginning and use flexbox, it will be much easier.

Comment: @Dark0ctane please add your HTML code, so that we can see the performance issues in rendering of Your HTML

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/NI2T4hd this is what it looks like

Answer (score 1):

I've pasted your code into a Codepen here: https://codepen.io/blueocto/pen/ZEzjxwK

1. First of all, `margin: 0 auto` on an element that is floated will not work. When it floats, it is taken out of the flow of the document
2. You don't need to `position: relative` all the things
3. I assumed you wanted to centrally align the image, title, paragraph and link ... this will happen as the `text-align: center` on your testimonial will cascade
4. I've added some styles for your images (placeholders) so they centrally align above your title

I hope that is what you were looking to achieve.

*If my answer did help solve your issue, I'd really appreciate the upvote, thank you.*

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn your `position: relative` to `position: initial`

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/1ce9kpms/1/)

Answer (score -1):

The performance issues because of CSS

The problem in your CSS is

```
.testimonial a{
position: relative;
............
............
............
}
```

every time the browser reads position relative, browser try to re-render the dom!

So please try your CSS like this

```
.testimonial{
    position: relative;
    }

   a{
.........
.........
    }
img{
....
....
}
```

so that re-rendering does not cause an issue.

You can use Chrome DevTools for checking Performance issues at the browser end.
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/